# Fluents of more than one goal in prolog

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

This is a block world problem which is going to move the blocks where we want them to be.
The predicate `located_on` tells us the locations of blocks according to the fluents. The `goal_state` is where we want the blocks to be.

The third parameter of `located_on` is ***situations(fluents)***, which indicates the ***action history***.

The fluent ***starts*** at ***empty list*** which means no action has been done yet. After each action, we add the action into the third parameter fluent.

For example, if we move a to b, then move b to c, then move c to d, the fluent would be `[move(c,d),move(b,c),move(a,b)]`. We can know where each blocks are according to ***fluents(their action history)***.

```
%Successor states
located_on(A,B,[move(A,B)|_]).
located_on(B,L,[_|S]) :- located_on(B,L,S).

%Goal state
goal_state(S):- located_on(a,b,S),located_on(d,area2,S).
```

The problem is that, when I have only one goal, say `goal_state(S):- located_on(a,b,S)`, I can get all possible fluents S:

```
?- goal_state(X).
X = [] ;
X = [move(a, b)|_G4037] ;
X = [_G4036] ;
X = [_G4036, move(a, b)|_G4040] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, move(a, b)|_G4043] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042, move(a, b)|_G4046] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042, _G4045] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042, _G4045, move(a, b)|_G4049]
```

**But** when I have more than one goals, say `goal_state(S):- located_on(a,b,S),located_on(d,area2,S).`, the fluents I get get stuck in one of its goals:

```
?- goal_state(X).
X = [] ;
X = [move(a, b)] ;
X = [move(a, b), move(d, area2)|_G344] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, move(d, area2)|_G347] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, move(d, area2)|_G350] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, _G349] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, _G349, move(d, area2)|_G353] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, _G349, _G352] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, _G349, _G352, move(d, area2)|_G356] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, _G349, _G352, _G355] ;
X = [move(a, b), _G343, _G346, _G349, _G352, _G355, move(d, area2)|_G359]
```

The first element here are aways `move(a,b)` since the program get infinite loop in satisfying `move(d, area2)`.
Is there any way that can help me **get rid of the infinite loop**?

The whole program is like this:

```
%Initial states
initial_state([]).
located_on(a,b,[]).
located_on(b,c,[]).
located_on(c,area1,[]).
located_on(d,area2,[]).


%Successor states
located_on(A,B,[move(A,B)|_]).
located_on(B,L,[_|S]) :- located_on(B,L,S).

%Goal state
goal_state(S):- located_on(a,b,S),located_on(d,area2,S),located_on(b,d,S),located_on(c,area1,S).

%Poss
poss(move(A,B),S) :- member(A,[a,b,c,d]),member(B,[a,b,c,d,area1,area2,area3]),
    \+A=B,clear(A,S),clear(B,S).

clear(A,S) :- member(A,[a,b,c,d,area1,area2,area3]), \+located_on(_,A,S).

%Solve problem
legal_move(S,A,[A|S]):-poss(A,S).

plan(L) :- initial_state(I), goal_state(G), reachable(I,L,G).

reachable(S,[],S).
reachable(S1,[M|L],S3) :- legal_move(S1,M,S2), reachable(S2,L,S3).
```

I solve the problem by replacing `plan(L) :- initial_state(I), goal_state(G), reachable(I,L,G).` with `plan(L) :- initial_state(I), reachable(I,L,G), goal_state(G).`

That means instead of generating all possible goal_states, we first try every reachable positions and then check if they are goal states. In this way we get unified G when dealing with goal_state.

Here is the answer from prolog:

```
24 ?- plan([A,B,C]).
A = move(a, area3),
B = move(b, d),
C = move(a, b)  ;
false.
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the third parameter? It's a list I guess but what does it contain??

Comment: So if S contains move(a,b) and you ask located_on(a,b,S) what do you expect?

Comment: I am just trying to know all the possibilities that may lead to a on b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this formulation, you can't get rid of the infinite recursion alltogther because moving a block between to a new state and back creates a cycle in the graph, which corresponds to an infinite list.

What you can do is to perform an iterative deepening search by unifiying the solution with an arbitrary list first:

```
:- length(S,_), goal_state(S).
```

first, S is unified with a list of length 0, on which goal_state is tried. After all lists of length an were tried, length unifies with a list of length 1, etc.

Edit: thanks  to mat for identifying the correct search strategy!

Comment: +1, but that's not breadth-first search (BFS): It is depth-first iterative deepening, which is an asymptotically optimal search method in both time and space under quite general assumptions.

Comment: Thank you! I found another way to solve the problem by unifying S first and then use the predict goal_state.